# Sampling triplet sets in the field of few-shot learning

Tags: few-shot-learning, triplet-loss-function

I have recently been exposed to the concept of K-way N-shot classification. As far as I realize few-shot learning involves meta training and meta testing sets for training and testing our model, respectively. In each set there are some tasks and each task have query (include K classes containing N samples) and support (include samples from N classes) sets, the sample classes of both sets are the same while the classes of meta training and meta testing are different. On the other hand, in triple loss there are a triple set containing anchor, positive (with same label) and negative (a different label of anchor and positive).
I cannot find suitable solution for samples triplet sets from query and support sets. What is the process for sampling triplet sets in few-shot learning, specifically in the query and support sets, and how does it contribute to the overall accuracy of the model?